# what "[Error] invalid operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'float *')" means

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

ATYB bank gives 5 students scholarship awards for the next three years at college
Enter the various scholarship amounts for each student using pointer notation
Use a module called totalschol that 2 arguments, and an array and a pointer to the array.
This module outputs(using pointer notation) the total amount of each student for the next three years

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Function Prototype..
void totSchol(float total [], float *aPointer);

int main(void)
{
    // Declare Local Variables..
    int i;
    float amt[5]={0}, tot;
    //points to the array variable.
    float *aPointer = &amt[0];
    //prompts AYTB Bank..
    printf("\t\t AYTB Bank\n");
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        //prompts to enter scholarship amount for 5 students..
        printf("Student %d, Enter scholarship amount: ", i+1);
        //takes value entered and store in pointer variable aPointer & increment by i..
        scanf("%f", aPointer + i);
        tot += aPointer;
    }

    totSchol(amt, aPointer);
    
    return 0;
}


void totSchol(float total [], float *aPointer)
{
    int x;
    float year3;
    
    for (x=0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        
        printf("\nThe total amount for each studetn is: %.2f", (aPointer + x));
        year = (aPointer +x) * 3;
        printf("\nThe total amount for each studetn after 3 years is: %.2f", year3);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: tot += aPointer;

Comment: The use of `aPointer + x` in `totSchol` is incorrect too, you mean `aPointer[x]`

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says - you're trying to add a `float` to a `float *` and that's not allowed (you can only add integers to pointers, and the result is another pointer).  It happens here:

```
tot += aPointer;
```

You probably meant to write

```
tot += aPointer[i];
```

`aPointer` points to the first element of the `amt` array, so `aPointer[i]` is equivalent to `amt[i]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, a simple thing like that can mess up the code I see, and also I added ```year3= aPointer[x] * 3;``` to my Function Definition. It works thank you...